# Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py

I contain my app in a file called `application.py`, and my application's configuration looks like this:

[image]

I also tried uploading the sample app that AWS provides, which only contains 'application.py`, and yet I still get this error.

What could be causing the error?

Answer (score 5):

For me, it was this silly thing. In my mac, I compressed by right-clicking on the folder/repository and compressing it to zip. However, a zip like that extracts to open another folder within it which contains the application. As a result, EBS is unable to locate application.py. 
The simple fix hence was to select all the individual files inside the folder to create the zip file for uploading (or using the EB CLI to upload).

Comment: I was making a similar mistake.  Another option is to use awsebcli so you can deploy with `eb deploy` and not have to create and upload a zip at all.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue. You should put your `application.py` in root directory as your WSGIPath suggests, or change your WSGIPath in `.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.yourappname-env`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had my app instance stored in a variable called `app`, which wasn't recognised by Elastic Beanstalk. As soon as I changed the variable to `application`, it started working.

```
# In application.py or manage.py, after initialising the app
application = app
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use `application` instead of `app` or any other variable you are using.

```
application = Flask(__name__)
```