# Flask Application Error AWS "Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask

I looked at this question and the answer was not helpful [Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713871/target-wsgi-script-not-found-or-unable-to-stat)

So I have this error `Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py` with a log that looks like this:

```
-------------------------------------
[Mon Feb 27 06:30:18.662493 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 2814] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Feb 27 06:30:18.683705 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2814] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Feb 27 06:30:18.684297 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2814] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Feb 27 06:30:18.685851 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2814] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 27 06:30:18.685868 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2814] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Feb 27 06:31:13.692724 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2814] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Feb 27 06:31:14.807849 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 3107] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Feb 27 06:31:14.818836 2017] [so:warn] [pid 3107] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Feb 27 06:31:14.823227 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 3107] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Feb 27 06:31:14.823836 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3107] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Mon Feb 27 06:31:14.825753 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3107] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Feb 27 06:31:14.825767 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3107] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Mon Feb 27 06:31:17.412531 2017] [:error] [pid 3114] [client 127.0.0.1:49512] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Mon Feb 27 06:31:18.414605 2017] [:error] [pid 3113] [client 127.0.0.1:49514] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Mon Feb 27 06:31:19.416729 2017] [:error] [pid 3115] [client 127.0.0.1:49516] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Mon Feb 27 06:31:20.418697 2017] [:error] [pid 3116] [client 127.0.0.1:49518] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Mon Feb 27 06:32:37.369544 2017] [:error] [pid 3116] [client 172.31.25.204:44521] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Mon Feb 27 06:32:38.135561 2017] [:error] [pid 3116] [client 172.31.25.204:44521] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Mon Feb 27 06:32:38.229702 2017] [:error] [pid 3116] [client 172.31.25.204:44521] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Mon Feb 27 06:33:31.412746 2017] [:error] [pid 3260] [client 172.31.25.204:44613] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Mon Feb 27 06:35:09.997950 2017] [:error] [pid 3116] [client 172.31.25.204:44703] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py
[Mon Feb 27 06:35:10.172663 2017] [:error] [pid 3116] [client 172.31.25.204:44703] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /opt/python/current/app/application.py, referer: http://my.url/
```

My application was configured with `eb init -p python3.4 myApp` then `eb create myEnv` then `eb deploy`.

.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml has

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: myEnv
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: myApp
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: python3.4
  default_region: us-west-2
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
```

The application.py file is at the same level as the .elasticbeanstalk folder.

I also tried:

```
branch-defaults:
  master:
    environment: myEnv
    group_suffix: null
environment-defaults:
  myEnv:
    branch: null
    repository: null
global:
  application_name: myApp
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: python3.4
  default_region: us-west-2
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: application.py
```

Comment: And does ``/opt/python/current/app/application.py`` actually exist? What are the permissions on the file? What are the permissions on the parent directories?